# symfony2 upload image yml

Tags: image, symfony, upload

i need some help
I have a bundle using yml my probleme is that 
i can't upload image using yml ,i need to make a foreign key between Image entity and product entity so i can't show image for every product .
please take a look

```
<?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Piece
*/
class Piece
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $designation;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $description;
```

Image doctrine :

```
FrontOfficeBundle\Entity\Image:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: FrontOfficeBundle\Entity\ImageRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    path:
        type: string
        length: 255
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html And for each part related to mapping in the guide, select YAML instead of annotations.